Personal .sty and .cls files creation
I have recently been more and more interested in the LaTeX dark side (i.e. developping commands, packages, globally playing and trying stuff for fun and knowledge - so jk I know it is not that dark (: ), but I am currently facing some questions. I have the MiKTeX Console currently installed and updated, and I am working with the last version of TeXMaker on Windows 10.
Here are my objectives at the moment :

Switch from pdfLaTeX to LuaLaTeX : as far as I understand, the second one allows for more automatization (which I like), function development, maths, etc. I believe I understood that I only need to put the fontspec and luacode packages in the preamble and everything should be alright.
Create my own documents' style (thus class ?) for all the papers I will write : articles, reports, beamers, letters, books, etc.

And here are the issues/questions :

I am not sure I correctly understand the objective of each file type. As far as I know, the .cls files define how works and looks a whole class of documents (like articles, books, beamers, etc.) ; while the .sty ones can be called through a command in a chosen document in order to make it look how we want it to. Is that right ?
I would like the papers' code to be as clean as possible in terms of preamble content : then, is it possible to include all my reguarly used packages (which are around 40) in a single .cls or .sty file that I would call in my papers' code ? Also I did not find where I should put my "homemade" style and class files, even after looking at this question and this one too.
Finally, is it possible to use some Lua code in those particular files ? More generally, can we set up commands to define graphs, tables and lists in the style and class files that I would only need to call in my main file ? Is everything really configurable ? (understand : can parameters be implemented in every single command ?)

I know this post has several themes and questions, but I would like to combine every aspect of it in order to produce some clean, personal documents that I would not have to update-check everytime I open one, and without an endless preamble aswell.
Thank you for any help you could provide <3

The first question is answered in Classes and packages – what's the difference?

(2) Yes, you can. Put them in TEXMFHOME/tex/latex/ where TEXMFHOME is your personal TeX tree. kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFHOME will tell you the directory. (3) If they are your commands, they can ave parameters or not as you wish and that has nothing to do with Lua.

You do not need to load any package to use lualatex. However, you probably will want to load fontspec. The main thing is not to load packages which shouldn't be used with a unicode engine.

Details of where to put them are in https://latex.silmaril.ie/formattinginformation/personal.html

There is also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1137/where-do-i-place-my-own-sty-or-cls-files-to-make-them-available-to-all-my-te/1167#1167. However, I can't honestly recommend any of the answers there. Even those written by high-rep users and which have many votes are misleading or outright wrong in part.

Note that people will recommend you not do this :-). They will tell you to start with an empty preamble for each document. I'm sure this is excellent advice, but it is not advice I follow.

As one of the people @cfr is referring to :) here's a set of reasons why you shouldn't make a default preamble package. Creating a default preamble

@AlanMunn Oh, if that's what people mean, I do actually try to follow it, though this is more aspiration than reality as I have a bunch of old stuff which is conceptually muddled. (Which isn't to say my new stuff isn't conceptually muddled, but it is at least conceptually muddled in different ways.) But following that advice is consistent with starting almost all documents with a custom class, isn't it?

@cfr If you make documents of a particular type repeatedly, then yes it makes sense to have a custom class to do that. But most requests like this tend to be "I load a lot of these packages in most of my documents so why not make a package to load them always" which is IMO not a good strategy.

@AlanMunn Yes. No. I agree. I'm just thought I didn't agree.
